# Why can't my project code access my CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm using `CocoaPods` to add `SnapKit` to my iOS project. However, none of the functions from `SnapKit` are accessible from my source code. Xcode immediately throws a compiler warning along this lines of "this doesn't exist"

I followed the install instructions listed [here](http://snapkit.io/docs/). I also have the `xcworkspace` open that `CocoaPods` created and I see my app project and a `Pods` project. I did notice that under `Pods/Product` in the navigator I see `Pods.framework` and `SnapKit.framework` in red. When I run `find . | grep SnapKit.framework` in my project directory, nothing turns up.

After digging around I believe `SnapKit.framework` is in my `DerviedData` folder under `~/Library/Developer/XCode`. I did notice that under the build settings for Pods `PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILDPATH` is set to look in a `builds` directory under my project, which does not exist. Perhaps that's the issue? Are my pods supposed to build in a `build` directory? How would I make them do that?

Additionally, both my project and the library are written entirely in swift.

Comment: Did you open the projet in the Xcode workspace that was created by Cocoapods or in the regular Xcode project file after having pulled in your dependencies?

Comment: Have you configured bridging header?

Comment: @nburk I have the workspace open

Comment: @Azat The library I'm using is written in Swift, so I believe a bridging header would be unnecessary?

Comment: @Liam yes. Sorry I misunderstood your question. It is quite common issue to connect Objective-C code to Swift, but someone removed swift tag from your question

Comment: @Azat No problem, I forgot to mention in my original text I was using Swift. I updated it to be more clear.

Comment: @Liam which version of CocoaPods you are using? Right now I followed by your link and successfully integrated it to demo project. Maybe you missing something very simple like `import SnapKit`?

Comment: @Azat Wow, I feel silly. I just needed to `import SnapKit` for some reason I assumed that I didn't need to import other Swift files, but clearly that's not true for Frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you missing something very simple like:

```
import SnapKit
```

This will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue after installing SnapKit with CocoaPods.

I performed the installation correctly and inserted the import SnapKit line as required, but my project simply was not recognising the SnapKit framework. The import line produced a "no such module" error.

So I tried building the project without SnapKit and then like magic the SnapKit framework was recognised after that. I put back the import SnapKit line and everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost entirely certain that this is an edge case just for me, but I was editing a podfile and installing in the Trash.

Definitely picking the correct folder helped ;)